# Доступ к проинициализированным полям класса C++ из Python. (Создать копию существущего объекта C++ в Python)

Tags: c++, python, boost

Добрый день.

У меня следующая задача: имеется класс написанный на `C++` в котором есть поле `std::vector<double> body_` которое заполняется некоторыми внутренними методам, и мне необходимо передать это поле (**ПРОИНИЦИАЛИЗИРОВАННОЕ КОНКРЕТНЫМИ ЗНАЧЕНИЯМИ**) в модуль на `python`, выполнить с ним определенные манипуляции и вернуть обратно результат.

Как **наиболее эффективно** выполнить такую последовательность действий?

Для встраивания в `C++` модуля `Python` я использую `python.boost`. 
Рылся в документации `python.boost` ничего не нашел. 
Идеи в том чтобы как-то использовать `shared memory` или чисто посылать `*.json` из `C++` в модуль `Python`, там его читать, делать функции и полсылать `*.json` с ответом обратно, но мне кажется это неэффективным.

Буду благодарен за помощь.

Comment: покажите как у вас получается не "наиболее эффективным" способом это сделать.

Comment: К сожалению до конца работащего кода пока нет, как будет сразу выложу. Хотелось бы определить можно ли решить задачу средствами `python.boost` или придется использовать дополнительные средства.

Comment: для крошечных задач, обычно лучше, сперва рабочее решение создать, а потом только оптимизировать (когда ясно что должно получиться, насколько ускорить и тестировать можно)¶ Если забыть о "проинициализированное", то есть минимальный рабочий код? Или вообще не ясно как расширение для Питона писать?